# Set start-time for histogram sample

Tags: grafana, prometheus, prometheus-java

## The usecase

We got multiple changelogs stored in the database, and want to create a histogram monitoring the duration between changes.

## The problem

There doesn't seem to be a way to set the start time of a  `Historgram.Timer`, e.g we want to set it to `lastUpdated` given the current changelog.

## Avenues of approach

### 1 Subclassing `Histogram`

Should work. However the java-lib use `protected`/`package-private` extensively, thus making it hard without copying large portions of the library.

### 2 Using reflection

After a `Histogram.Timer` is created it should be possible to use reflection to set the `start` field. The field is marked as `private final`, and thus a SecurityManager could stop us in some environments.

## Ideas?

Neither of the solutions seems like the correct way to go, and I suspect that I'm overlooking a simpler solution (but could find anything at SO or google). We're using grafana to visualize our metrics, if thats at all helpful in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to subclass `Histogram`, as you don't need to use `Histogram.Timer` only because your histogram is measuring times.

Simply call `myHistogram.observe(System.now() - lastUpdated)` every time you record a new change in the database.

Comment: Thx, I actually figured it out after posting, but forgot to close this post.
Anyways, I'll leave the post her now.